# I want to split the data depending on a number of IDs

Tags: r, split

This is the original data.

```
str(demo$ID)
chr [1:5000] "Q05910452" "Q00509389" "Q59112261" "Q38120745" ...

str(ID.unique)
chr [1:4785, 1] "Q00027726" "Q00071545" "Q00073883" "Q00077269" ...
```

What I want to do is to make two data sets, one of which has 4785 IDs from demo$ID that are exactly same with ID.unique.

The other data set I want to make consists of the other IDs (215 IDs = 5000 - 4785) which are not included in ID.unique.

How can I do this? Please give a big help. Thank you very much.

Comment: You can use set operations for this. See `?intersect` and `?setdiff`.

Comment: Next time please provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try

```
indx <- demo$ID %in% ID.unique
lst <- split(demo, indx+1) #returns a list with two elements
```

#### data

```
ID.unique <- paste0('Q000', 1:5000)
set.seed(24)
demo <- data.frame(ID=sample(c(ID.unique, paste0('Q000', 5001:6000)),
              5000,replace=FALSE), Col2=rnorm(5000))
```

Comment: Really sorry for the late reply. Thank you for your help! Have a good day.